# javascript function only working for first row in table

Tags: javascript, php

I have set up a simple php site where you can filter through a table. At the end of each entry there is a link called "Details" which redirects the user to a site that displays the details of each entry. I want to change the link depending on the filter value the user inputs.

Here is the javascript:

```
function filterRows() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, cell, i, j, detailLink;
    input = document.getElementById("filterfeld");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("ftable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {

            tr[i].style.display = "none";
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (var j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
                cell = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j];

                if (cell) {


                    if (cell.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                        detailLink = cell.innerHTML;
                        if(detailLink.indexOf("href=") && document.getElementById("details").getAttribute('href') != "http://google.at"){
                            var el = document.querySelector('.details');
                            console.log(el.getAttribute('href'));
                            el.setAttribute('href',"http://google.at");
                            console.log(el.getAttribute('href'));
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

}
```

html table:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<table align='center' id='ftable' class='ftable'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><<th>E-Mail</th><th>Telefon</th><th>Geburtsdatum</th><th>Straße</th><th>Details</th></tr>";
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo "<td></td><tr><td>" . $row["id"] . "</td><td>" . $row["firstname"] ."&nbsp;". $row["lastname"] . "</td><td>" . $row["email"] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row["phone"] . "</td><td>" . $row["birthdate"] . "</td><td>" . $row["street"] . "</td>
                <td><a href='singleentry.php?id=" .$row["id"]."' class='details' id='details'>Details</a></td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
```

I have filled in the example link google.at.
Normally it should change all the links I have in my current table `ftable`.
The problem is it changes only the first link in the table and then stops.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre], not just JS code that lacks context. (And please show the resulting HTML, not any PHP code that we lack the setup and / or data for to be able to create an appropriate example.)

Comment: The entire JS code seems very fragile. You loop through all the TR tags on the UI and not just the ones of table with ID `ftable`. Then you start with the second TR tag since your loop starts with 1 instead of 0. This might even be the reason why it only works for row 0 ;-)

Comment: @eX0du5 the tr loop starting with 1 is wanted as tr0 would be the table headings.